# Is the map generator from the EPFL online course able to generate every possible map?

Tags: scala, generator

https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun2 assignment for Week 1 shows, as an example, a generator for maps of type `Map[Int, Int]`:

```
lazy val genMap: Gen[Map[Int,Int]] = oneOf(
  const(Map.empty[Int,Int]),
  for {
    k <- arbitrary[Int]
    v <- arbitrary[Int]
    m <- oneOf(const(Map.empty[Int,Int]), genMap)
  } yield m.updated(k, v)
)
```

I'm new to Scala, but I'm familiar with generators in imperative programming languages. My understanding of the generator's execution flow is as follows:

1. `arbitrary[Int]` is called, it returns a generator yielding an endless sequence of `Int`s, the first generated value is assigned to `k`
2. `arbitrary[Int]` is called again, it returns a new generator, the first generated value is assigned to `v`
3. A random map is created recursively, updated with `k->v`, and yielded to the consumer
4. When the next value from the generator is requested, the execution resumes at `m <- ...` definition, proceeding with a new random `m` and **the same** `k->v` mapping
5. Neither `const` nor the recursive `genMap` ever run out of values, meaning that the "loop" for `m` never terminates, so new values for `v` and `k` are never requested from the corresponding `arbitrary` generators.

My conclusion is that all generated maps would either be empty or include the `k->v` mapping generated in the first iteration of the outermost invocation, i.e. `genMap` can never generate a non-empty map without such a mapping.

Q1: are my analysis and my conclusion correct?

Q2: if they are, how can I implement a generator which, after generating a first map, would have non-zero chance of generating **any** possible map?

Q3: if I simplify the last definition in the `for`-expression to `m <- genMap`, does that change the generator's behaviour in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, your analysis and conclusion aren't correct.

I suspect the root of the misunderstanding is in interpreting `for` as a loop (it's not in general, and specifically not so in this context (when dealing with things that are more explicitly collections, `for` is close enough, I guess)).

I'll explain from the top down.

`oneOf`, given 1 or more generators will create a generator which, when asked to generate a value, will defer to one of the the given generators by random selection.  So

```
oneOf(
  const(Map.empty[Int, Int]),
  k: Gen[Map[Int, Int]]  // i.e. some generator for Map[Int, Int]
)
```

The output might be

```
someMapFromK, Map.empty, someMapFromK, someMapFromK, Map.empty, Map.empty...
```

In this case, our `k` is

```
for {
  k <- arbitrary[Int]
  v <- arbitrary[Int]
  m <- oneOf(const(Map.empty[Int, Int]), genMap)  // genMap being the name the outermost generator will be bound to
} yield m.updated(k)
```

`for` is syntactic sugar for calls to `flatMap` and `map`:

```
arbitrary[Int].flatMap { k =>
  arbitrary[Int].flatMap { v =>
    oneOf(const(Map.empty[Int, Int]), genMap).map { m =>
      m.updated(k, v)
    }
  }
}
```

For something like `List`, `map` and `flatMap` consume the entire collection.  `Gen` is lazier:

- `flatMap` basically means generate a value, and feed that value to a function that results in a `Gen`
- `map` basically means generate a value, and transform it

If we imagined a method on `Gen` named `sample` which gave us the "next" generated value (for this purpose, we'll say that for a `Gen[T]` it will result in `T` and never throw an exception, etc.)  `genMap` is exactly analogous to:

```
trait SimpleGen[T] { def sample: T }

lazy val genMap: SimpleGen[Map[Int, Int]] = new SimpleGen[Map[Int, Int]] {
  def sample: Map[Int, Int] =
    if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) Map.empty
    else {
      val k = arbitrary[Int].sample
      val v = arbitrary[Int].sample
      val m =
        if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) Map.empty
        else genMap.sample // Since genMap is lazy, we can recurse
      m.updated(k, v)
    }
  }
```

Regarding the third question, in the original definition, the extra `oneOf` serves to bound the recursion depth to prevent the stack from being blown.  For that definition, there's a 1/4 chance of going recursive, while replacing the inner `oneOf` with `genMap` would have a 1/2 chance of going recursive.  Thus (ignoring the chance of a collision in the `k`s), for the first:

- 50% chance of empty (50% chance of 1+)
- 37.5% chance of size 1 (12.5% chance of 2+)
- 9.375% chance of size 2 (3.125% chance of 3+)
- 2.34375 chance of size 3 (0.78125% chance of 4+)...

While for the second:

- 50% chance of empty
- 25% chance of size 1
- 12.5% chance of size 2
- 6.25% chance of size 3...

Technically the possibility of stack overflow implies that depending on how many recursions you can make there's a maximum number of `k -> v` pairs in the `Map` you can generate, so there are almost certainly `Map`s that could not be generated.